# Serializing an IHttpActionResult as JSON causes exception

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I've got a little Web API 2 app where I'm trying to implement logging of the incoming request and the outgoing response (basically to log what you'd see as the HTTP traffic via Fiddler2).

In trying to serialize the response from a method, I'm getting exceptions that I'm not sure how to deal with.  I've tried playing with the JsonSerializerSettings and so forth.  I may be going about doing this the entirely wrong way.  Would appreciate any guidance.

Here's the snip of code that causes the exception.

```
var response = Ok(successMessage);
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling=Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
};
this.Logging.LogMessage(MessageType.ServiceResponse, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented, settings));
return response;
```

The exception:

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'. ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.   at System.IO.Stream.get_ReadTimeout()   at GetReadTimeout(Object ) 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a 1 to many relationship within the response? Does the response contain a list and within that list item it contains a reference back to the response?

When building a json child nodes can not reference their parent on you will have an infinite loop when trying to serialize.

Build a view model and remove the reference back to parent. Just pass the parentid.

Comment: Hold on a sec. Why don't you just return ok (successmessage)

Comment: because I want to log the response in a database.  This is a simple example, but we'd also want to log other response conditions where there's a request validation error and that sort of thing as well.